# Error importing pycurl, for one user

Tags: python, macos, pycurl

I have installed pycurl (see [Cannot install pycurl on Mac OS X - get errors 1 and 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752405)) but one user gets this error:

```
>> import pycurl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/pycurl.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/pycurl.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dlopen(/Volumes/vData/Users/pkearns/.python-eggs/pycurl-7.19.0-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg-tmp/pycurl.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /Volumes/vData/Users/pkearns/.python-eggs/pycurl-7.19.0-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg-tmp/pycurl.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
>>>
```

The architecture is correct:

```
vger.local:~(6)+>- file /Volumes/vData/Users/pkearns/.python-eggs/pycurl-7.19.0-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg-tmp/pycurl.so
/Volumes/vData/Users/pkearns/.python-eggs/pycurl-7.19.0-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg-tmp/pycurl.so: Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64
vger.local:~(7)+>- uname -m
x86_64
vger.local:~(8)+>-
```

This is what else I checked so far:

- The `sys.path` for the problem user is the same as that for other users
- I removed `~/.python-eggs`
- I deleted pycurl and re-added (I didn't
  expect that to make any difference)
- I searched for any other occurances of pycurl and removed them

Comment: What does `mach-o, but wrong architecture` mean?

Comment: @PeterWood That would suggest Python found a binary for PowerPC (for example) instead of 64-bit Intel, but I checked and the architecture is correct.  I'll amend my question to show that.

Comment: I'll ask the perhaps obvious thing, but the Python you start with (in which you `import pycurl`), is that the correct architecture, and the same as for other users?

Comment: @Evert No harm to ask the obvious questions, but the Python I'm using is completely functional otherwise, no problem importing any other modules.